# Get controller instance from callback

Tags: ember.js

I have a login controller that calls a method when accepted, or rejected. Here's a snippet of the rejected code:

```
authFailed: function() {
  var c = App.__container__.lookup("controller:login");
  c.set('errorMessage', 'Authentication Failed');
}
```

I know the `__container__` is a hack, however it worked up until recently. Today I started a project using ember-app-kit, and noticed that this no longer works. What is the correct way of  getting the controller instance?

**update:**

Its worth noting, that this controller references itself, ie the login controller contains `authFailed` which is called from an ajax callback after the authentication request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jquery ajax, you can set the context option to the controller using `context: this`, so the callbacks of `then` method, will have `this` like controller instance.

Probally you will have something like this:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var username = ... 
      var password = ...
      Ember.$.ajax('user/auth', { data: { username: username, password: password }, context: this }).then(this.authSuccess, this.authFailed);
    }
  },
  authFailed: function() {
    this.set('errorMessage', 'Authentication Failed');
  },
  // more code ...
});
```